Create bash script that calls a python script which takes in positional arguments, named arguments and flags
I would like to create a bash-script that calls a python script. The python script accepts both positional arguments, named arguments and boolean flags. The idea is that the bash script passes whatever the users provides over to the python script.
Take this python script example.py as an example:
import argparse

def run(positional_argument,named_argument='default',flag=False):
    print(positional_argument)
    print(named_argument)
    print(flag)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # add positional arguments
    parser.add_argument('positional_argument',type=str,choices=['a','b'])

    # add keyword arguments
    parser.add_argument('--named_argument',type=str,required=False,default='default')

    # add flags
    parser.add_argument('--flag',action='store_true')

    # parse arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # call function
    run(positional_argument=args.positional_argument,
        named_argument=args.named_argument,
        flag=args.flag)

Now write a script wrapper.sh that internally calls example.py
P.S.: Broader context for curious readers (although not strictly needed to solve my question): I would like to create a pip-package that can also be used as a command-line application. There's already an answer on that but it only covers positional arguments.

Aren't all arguments positional arguments?

You're right! The provided answer in the other script also works for my example

Glad it helped. FWIW, python example.py "$@" seems to work fine.

You script is already processing command line arguments. Why do you need a bash script as wrapper?

Answering my own question. The solution provided here also covers my example. So wrapper.sh would look like this:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if (( $# == 0 )); then
    python3 -m example -h
else
    python3 -m example "$@"
fi


Check your scripts with shellcheck. It's "$@" not $@, otherwise there will be problems .
